# "LoginPage" is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Good morning Devs... I am developing a Facebook clone where I have created a component called `LoginPage`, but it fails to render on the browser with the following error message: `"LoginPage not defined"`.

Below  is my App.js code

```js
import React from  "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (

1. export default App;
```

Below is my `LoginPage.js` code

```js
import React from "react";
import "./LoginPage.css";

function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <div className="facebook">
        <div className="facebook-text">facebook</div>
        <div className="title">
          Facebook helps you connect and share<br></br> wih the people in your
          life
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="logincontainer">
        <div className="logindetails">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email address or phone number" />
          <br></br>
          <input type="Password" placeholder="Password" />
          <br></br>

          <button className="btn">Login</button>

          <div className="forget">
            <a href="forget">Forgotten Password?</a>
          </div>
          <br></br>
          <div className="create">
            <br></br>
            <button className="btns">Create New Account</button>
          </div>
          <p></p>
          <br></br>
          <div className="page">
            <a href="createpage">Create Page</a> for a celebrity, brand or
            business
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default LoginPage;
```

I'm following a tutorial and I have checked all the possible syntax errors and i have seen none.

Comment: edit the code again it not clear

Comment: Please edit the question to update the `App.js` code. What you posted seems to miss essential parts of code.

Comment: OP did not provide all their code, they messed up pasting it probably.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import LoginPage.js` in your `App.js`, and then render the `LoginPage` component.